# Best DNN Module for Blog, Forum, Wiki

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, blogs, wiki, forum

I want to create a Community for our Shopsystem.

We want to use DNN as a development tool.

Now I'm searching for good modules for Blog, Forum and Wiki.

Paid modules and free modules are both interesting.

MfG SWegener

I haven't looked into much blogs until now. 
So if you know some which are helpful, please provide the URL.

Answer (score 0):

For Wiki, you may consider the Canam Wiki module - http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/canam-wiki-pro-2
It is the same one being used by DNN on their website.